# Solving a factorial expression by factoring

Tags: factorial

I'm trying to solve given factorial expression

$$\dfrac{(2n-1)!}{(3n-4)!} + \dfrac{(n+2)!}{(8-4n)!}$$

I noticed that there's $n!$ in common. Let me try to rewrite them.

$$\dfrac{n!\biggr [(2n-1)\cdot 1\biggr ]}{n!\biggr [(3n-4)(3n-3)(3n-2)(3n-1)\biggr ]}$$

However, I believe that my assumption is wrong so far.

Comment: is the denominator in the second therm really $(8-4n)!$? because then you're either taking factorial of negative numbers or $n$ must be smaller than or equal to $2$.

Comment: @kvphxga Yes, it is $(8-4n)!$

Comment: If we are *solving* this expression, is there something it is equal to?

Comment: Can't anyone comment on it?